# How to echo a $ sign in php

Tags: php, mysql

I use a mailscript with a dynamic body-field, so an admin user can build it's own BODY. But in the body I need the have some variables.

Example of an input of an admin user:

> Dear [name] from [company],
>   thanks for registering

This text will be INSERTed in a table. But now I want to use this input for building an automatic mail. So the content of $body should be:

> Dear $name from $company,
>   thanks for registering

This is my code:

```
$inserted_text = addslashes($_POST['inserted_text']);
   $patterns = array();
                            $patterns[0] = '/[name]/';
                            $patterns[1] = '/[company]/';

                            $replacements = array();
                            $replacements[1] = '$name';
                            $replacements[0] = '$company';
                            $inserted_text_dynamic = (preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $inserted_text));


$body = <html><head>...</head><body> $inserted_text_dynamic </body>

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

But the output goes wrong? How can I manage to have content like **$name** in my $body ?

Comment: The regular expressions `/[name]/ /[company]/` are probably not doing what you expect them to. You need to escape the square brackets, otherwise they are regexp character classes.  `/\[name\]/`

Comment: Your pattern doesn't match what you expect. You will have better results quoting it. Furthermore your indexes are mixed. You might consider using a template language for things like this.

Comment: I don't see a need to use `preg_replace()` here - plain old [`str_replace()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) supports array arguments, and is more appropriately used for static replacements like `[name]`.

Comment: What purpose does `addslashes` serve here? Seeing that in code is never a good sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work:

```
$replacements[1] = '$name';
$replacements[0] = '$company';
```

Use double-quotes:

```
$replacements[1] = "$name";
$replacements[0] = "$company";
```

or no quotes:

```
$replacements[1] = $name;
$replacements[0] = $company;
```

Use this:

```
$body = "<html><head>...</head><body> " . $inserted_text_dynamic . " </body>";
```

Instead of:

```
$body = <html><head>...</head><body> $inserted_text_dynamic </body>
```

And remove firts brackets in

```
$inserted_text_dynamic = (preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $inserted_text));
```

like this:

```
$inserted_text_dynamic = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $inserted_text);
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Only the [ and ] are not recognized as interpreters. Now every word with NAME in it will be changed, so the input [name] is translated to [$name]

Answer (score 3):

```
$replacements[1] = '$name';
$replacements[0] = '$company';
```

This won't work in the way you intend, because single-quotes suppress the expansion of variables.

Use double-quotes:

```
$replacements[1] = "$name";
$replacements[0] = "$company";
```

Or no quotes:

```
$replacements[1] = $name;
$replacements[0] = $company;
```

@MichaelBerkowski also correctly points out that you are using square brackets in your regular expression pattern, but square brackets are metacharacters in regular expressions, so you should escape them. Or else choose a different character to delimit your placeholders in your email template. Or use a function that does fixed string replacement instead of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it you can use it as

```
echo "Dear $name from $company, thanks for registering";
```

in double quotation marks variables are auto given there value or if you want to use single quotation marks then you ca try this.

```
echo 'Dear '.$name. ' from '.$company. ', thanks for registering';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things at play here - syntax errors and improper regex. [**Here**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/v0mn-zdhe) is a complete solution example.

```
$_POST['inserted_text'] = 'Dear [name] from [company], thanks for registering';
$name = 'foo';
$company = 'bar';
$inserted_text = addslashes($_POST['inserted_text']);
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/\[name\]/'; // you have to escape square brackets in regex because they are special to regex
$patterns[1] = '/\[company\]/';

$replacements = array();
$replacements[1] = $name; // removed quotes
$replacements[0] = $company; // removed quotes
$inserted_text_dynamic = (preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $inserted_text));

$body = '<body>' . $inserted_text_dynamic . '</body>';
echo $body;
```